# Multisite custom rewrite urls

Tags: multisite, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules, plugin-polylang

On a multisite installation, which is running the Polylang plugin, I want to add a custom rewrite rule.

Currently, my permalink structure is:

```
http://host.com/sitename/language/pagename
```

Now I want to add a querystring called country, as such:

```
http://host.com/sitename/country/language/pagename
```

I have tried the following, but to no avail:

```
function custom_rewrite_basic() {
  add_rewrite_tag('%country%', '([^&]+)');
  add_rewrite_rule('^([a-z]+)/?', 'index.php?country=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
```

Any thoughts?

-- EDIT

Getting closer, but still not there:

```
add_rewrite_tag('%country%', '([^&]+)');
add_rewrite_tag('%lang%', '([^&]+)');
add_rewrite_rule('^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?country=$matches[1]&lang=$matches[2]','top');
```

The problem here is that:

- polylang recognized the country as the language, even though the query var "lang" is set correctly
- WP thinks we are not on the home page anymore

Answer (score 0):

Your rule do not match the structure of the url you want. The rule basically handles urls with only a country. What is the right rule? you will need to look at the kind of rules the plugin produces and mimic them.

Comment: I updated my rule...